# Chrome doesn't show in list of browsers when setting default in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

After an update to both Windows 10 and Chrome (51.0.2704.103), my default browser has cleared:

[image]

and clicking the "+" button to choose the default only gives me the option of Edge and Firefox:

[image]

Does any one know why this is or what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes I have mixed results with the ModernUI default programs. Can you try opening Control Panel and using that interface?

Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs

[image: control panel defaults]

Comment: I forgot about the "old" way of doing it. I really wish MS would stop releasing half baked products where only half the options are in the new UI and you have to revert to the old UI to get anything done! Azure was like that for ages, and the office 365 admin console is currently doing it! Any way, it was the two URL protocols HTTP and HTTPS I needed to set chrome as the default for to get it to work.

Comment: A new Windows update seems to have eradicated this option.  When I click "Set your default programs" it takes me to the new Windows 10 "Default apps" page from the original question.  I can no longer find a way to get to this old-style iinterface pointed to in this answer.  I am using Chromium, and it is not listed as an option when I click "Choose a default" for "Web browser."  Since I can't set this, I can't open hyperlinks in Outlooks e-mails.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue as well on different installations.

As philosophickle said in his answer, try setting it through the control panel (+1).  That has worked for me.

Another option that has worked for me is to select a different browser, like Firefox, reboot and then (hopefully) Chrome will show in the list, allowing you to select it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by jayjzc doesn't seem to be working anymore, as pointed out by Keltari. This is the solution that is provided by Microsoft in case your app (Chrome) is not listed:

1. First go to **Default Apps** in Windows Setting.
2. Scroll down to find **Set defaults by app** as the last option and click on it.
3. Now you should be presented with a page of apps, scroll down until you see **Google Chrome**. (If you have multiple Chromes', just click on the first one you see and you should be fine).
4. Click on **Google Chrome**, and then **Manage**.
5. You should be on a page with Microsoft Edge as a default for most of them. (There are some other applications that you can set as default, but for now don't worry about them).
6. Finally, click on every Microsoft Edge application, and select Google Chrome. This should make Chrome as your default browser.